# Increment variable value in TFS build +1

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server (Version 15.117.26714.0) with predefined variable $(ProjectBuildNumber).

Is there any way to increment, during build process, value of variable with minor build number by +1?

```
$(ProjectBuildNumber)  =   663
```

So, that on next build it will be:

```
$(ProjectBuildNumber)  =   664
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't reference variables in the build number of the Build Definition. But what you can do is override the build number in the build itself. You can either use a magic log command or use my [VSTS Variables Task to set the Build.BuildNumber in the build itself](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks). The Variables Task does expand variable references. You could probably just set the value to the current value to get it expanded.

[image]

To issue the log command yourself use a batch script, PowerShell or bash to output the following specific string to the console:

> ##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]build number
>
> Update build number for current build. Example:
>
> ```
> ##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]my-new-build-number
> ```
>
> Minimum agent version: 1.88
>
> <sub>source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md</sub>

An alternative option is to use the $(Rev) option:

```
Build.BuildNumber = 1.1.$(Rev:.r)
```

That will automatically increase the variable each time the build runs.

To [update a variable in a Build Definition use yet another extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-BuildUpdating-Tasks):

[image]

These things combined should be able to get what you want.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, I cannot change variable value permanently, using build tasks? Just in project build context? The $(Rev) is not a variant, because there are multiple projects in VSTS, and every time I start project, $(Rev) value increasing.

Comment: No Rev just generates a unique version number. If you pre-pend you version number with the name of the project it will generate unique versions.

Comment: To change the variable permanently, use the extension here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-BuildUpdating-Tasks, but you'll also need to run the Set Variable task to make the build itself take on the correct value.

Answer (score 5):

In the variable section,

> > set the value of ProjectBuildNumber to $[counter('', 663)].

This will queue build starting with 663 as ProjectBuildNumber and increments by 1 for the subsequent queue of builds.

Comment: This also works for releases and re-deploys of releases!

Comment: See the Microsoft documentation for [counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **counter** function (*Expressions*) is not available in TFS 2018. In this old version the best solution for me is to use a PowerShell script as the first Task of the build. You can than have your parameter

> $(ProjectBuildNumber)

as an input argument, and place this inline script:

```
$ProjectBuildNumber=$args[0]
$ProjectBuildNumber++
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProjectBuildNumber;]$ProjectBuildNumber"
```

After this Task you can use your incremented ProjectBuildNumber variable in all subsequent Tasks.