# Azure pipeline how to increase variable value?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When building code using azure pipeline I read version from pom file as follows:

```
[xml]$pomXml = Get-Content .\pom.xml
# version
Write-Host $pomXml.project.version
$version=$pomXml.project.version
```

And then I need to update snapshot version inside my pom. If the `$version` value is something like `1.44.4`, how can I increase it to 1.44.5 inside shell script or any other way, because it seems like I cannot do operations on `$version` value.

Comment: Do you want to increase the version in the pom.xml? (read it, increase and save?)

Comment: My problem is how can I increase it inside pipeline? because something like `$version = $version +1` doesn't work

Comment: @Channa Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330425/increment-variable-value-in-tfs-build-1 You can use this extension to update the variable value: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-BuildUpdating-Tasks&ssr=false#qna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `[Version]` accellerator for this:

```
[xml]$pomXml = Get-Content .\pom.xml
$oldVersion = [version]$pomXml.project.version   # '1.44.4'
$newVersion = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $oldVersion.Major, $oldVersion.Minor, ($oldVersion.Build + 1)

$newVersion
```

Output:

```
1.44.5
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PowerShell script you can increase the number in this way:

```
# $version = 1.44.4
$splitted = $version.Split('.')
$splitted[2] = [int]$splitted[2] + 1
$newVersion = $splitted -join "."
# $newVersion = 1.44.5
# Now you can save the file with the new version:
$pomXml.Save("pom.xml")
```